# Magento 2 can't remove post params when reload

Tags: magento2.3, csv, post-data, post, submit-form

I'm trying to import stock using csv. When I click on submit, the import functionality works fine. But when i click on reload when it is posting then it loads until the post function completes.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!file_exists($mediaPath.'csv')) {
        mkdir($mediaPath.'csv', 0777, true);
    }
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; //returns the mimetype
    $allowed = array('text/csv');
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {?>
    <h1 class="error">Only CSV files allowed</h1>
    <tr>
        <td>Wrong format</td>
        <td>Wrong format</td>
        <td>Wrong format</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
   $model->addData([
    "title" => 'Title 01',
    "content" => 'Content 01',
    "summary" => "true",
    "create_at" => new \Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')
    ]);
    $saveData = $model->save();

    }else{    
    $displayFlag = 1;
    $csv =  $_FILES['file'];    
    $targetdir = $mediaPath;   
    $image_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = explode(".", $image_name);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $imagepath=$mediaPath."csv/".$image_name;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$imagepath)){
        $csvFile = file($imagepath);
        $data = [];
        foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
            $data[] = str_getcsv($line, ",", '"');
        }
        $keys = [];
        $result = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            if($key == 0){
                $keys = $value;
            }            
        }
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            if($key !== 0){
                $result[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
            }            
        }
        foreach($result as $key => $value){
            if(isset($value['sku'])){
                if($product->getIdBySku($value['sku'])) {
                    $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($value['sku']);
                    $stockItem->setQty($value['qty']);
                    $sku = $value['sku'];            
                    if($stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem)){                
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value['sku'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['qty'] ?></td>
                            <td>Updated</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }else{?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value['sku'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['qty'] ?></td>
                            <td>Updated</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }else{ ?>
                     <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value['sku'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['qty'] ?></td>
                            <td>Sku Not found</td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }else{
                ?>
                 <h1 class="error">Only CSV files allowed</h1>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wrong format</td>
                        <td>Wrong format</td>
                        <td>Wrong format</td>
                    </tr>
            <?php 
                break;
            }            
        }
    }
}
header('Location: http://192.168.31.236/magento/admin/grid/grid/index');
exit();
}
?>
</table>
```

I can't load any admin pages until this post function completed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/StockUpload

You are recreating so much functionality I think it would help to look at something already built

Comment: This module is great. But when I import I get this error 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/html/magento/app/code/Xigen/CsvUpload/view/adminhtml/ui_component/xigen_csvupload_csv_listing.xml" is invalid: Element 'argument': This element is not expected. Expected is ( dataProvider ). Line: 16

Comment: @RameshKR I thought maybe issue with extension but I've checked and it is is fine. I've tried developer mode. I've scanned XML. Do you have latest version 1.0.8? I've tested on 2.3.2 store. Perhaps you are using older/newer?

Comment: I'm using the latest 2.3.4